# Deleting a table row in JavaScript with OOP

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, html5

I started learning OOP in JavaScript at school and I have to do my homework in OOP. It is a shopping list, one fills in a product and price and that is put into an array, the array its contents are put in a table in HTML. The list also has got delete buttons for every product, I have thought about using `this` in JavaScript, as I am working in OOP, but I am sceptic because of the scope.

The idea is that one clicks "verwijder" on the webpage (EDIT: in the corresponding row) and the table row is gone. I have thought about using `this` but also about dynamically updating the table after removing the selected row from the array.

Who can advise me about what to do and how to do that correctly? I have uploaded my JavaScript here: http://jsfiddle.net/hNAZ9/

Mainly, it is about this piece of code:

```
    function ShoppingList(){
    this.items = [];
    this.setItem = function(product, price){
        var item = new Item(product, price);
        this.items.push(item);
    };
    this.render = function(){
        var placeHolder = document.getElementById("shoppingList");
        placeHolder.innerHTML = "";

        for(var i = 0; i <this.items.length; i++){
            var tr = document.createElement("tr");
            tr.id = i;

            var tdProduct = document.createElement("td");
            tdProduct.innerHTML = this.items[i].product;
            tr.appendChild(tdProduct);

            var tdPrice = document.createElement("td");
            tdPrice.innerHTML = this.items[i].price;
            tr.appendChild(tdPrice);

            var tdDel = document.createElement("td");
            tdDel.innerHTML = "Verwijder";
            tdDel.addEventListener("click", delItem, false);
            tr.appendChild(tdDel);

            placeHolder.appendChild(tr);
        }
    };
}

    function delItem(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // What do I have to do here?
}
```

Comment: You actually have a decent start right there with proper separation of concerns - actually better than most code I see in the web so for starters - good work. 

Some things I'd do differently:

 - That `getElementById` call inside `.render` is not needed. You can make that DOM query once and then have a reference to that element.  Also, the function you're looking for for removing elements from the array is `.splice`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Wow, thank you for your response, I am glad to hear that you are very content. :)
I will look into the `getElementById` inside of `.render` and I will also look into the function `.splice` and its usage. Thank you a lot for your very helpful comment!

Answer (score 2):

The trick is linking a row to its item object and vice-versa, so both are removed/added in lockstep.

There are *a lot* of ways of going about that, but given your original code, the following should be a pretty good way to go.

I'd suggest using a closure when defining the event handler to make things simpler. [Here's a simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4u7gE/1/) and here's the code

```
function ShoppingList() {
    var that  = this, // keep a scope reference
        table = document.getElementById("shoppingList"); // find this once (only works if the page has been loaded already)

    this.items = [];

    // this adds an item to the array and a row to the table
    this.addItem = function (product, price) {
        var item = new Item(product, price);
        this.items.push(item);
        table.appendChild(buildRow(item));
    };

    // this removes the given item from the array and the table
    this.removeItem = function (item) {
        for(var i = 0 ; i < this.items.length ; i++) {
            if(this.items[i] === item) {
                this.items.splice(i, 1);
                break; // skip the rest of the loop, since we've found what we need
            }
        }
        table.removeChild(item.row); // remove the row
    }

    // this isn't actually needed as rows get added by addItem,
    // but it'll work just fine regardless
    this.render = function(){
        table.innerHTML = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++){
            table.appendChild(buildRow(this.items[i]));
        }
    };

    // an internal helper. This can be moved to the Item prototype
    // since it's not actually dependent on anything in ShoppingList
    function buildRow(item) {
        // an internal, internal helper
        function buildCell(text) {
            var td = document.createElement("td");
            td.innerHTML = text;
            return td;
        }

        // store the table row object on the item itself
        item.row = document.createElement("tr");

        item.row.appendChild(buildCell(item.product));
        item.row.appendChild(buildCell(item.price));

        var deleteCell = buildCell("Verwijder");
        item.row.appendChild(deleteCell);

        // set the event listener here, where we can access `item` and `tr`
        deleteCell.addEventListener("click", function () {
            that.removeItem(item); // remove the item. Here we need the `that` var
        }, false);

        return item.row;
    }
}
```